# Chef : Password-less sudo to chef client as part of an ANT script

Tags: exec, chef-infra, sudo, knife

On the Chef workstation, I use the command -

```
    knife ssh 'name:myserver.org.com' -x myUserName -P myClearTextPassword  "sudo chef-client"
```

This works fine, **prompts for my sudo password** and executes the cookbook on the destination chef node. So far so good.

Now, I am trying to do this, as part of a build operation in a Jenkins job in an ANT script which runs on a Windows System. The ANT script is as follows -

```
    <project name="MyProject" default="init" basedir=".">
<target name="init">
    <property name="mypassword" value="myClearTextPassword" />
    <echo message="Executing the knife script"/>
    <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true" inputstring="${mypassword}">
        <arg line="/c knife ssh name:myserver.org.com -x myUserName -P myClearTextPassword sudo chef-client" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The ANT script, when executed waits on the SUDO password -

```
    C:\chef-repo>ant
    Buildfile: C:\chef-repo\build.xml
    init:
    [echo] Executing the knife script
    [exec] cwllx0001.hq.target.com knife sudo password:
```

My aim is to execute this ANT script such that it **DOES NOT** wait for the sudo password. Any way we can achieve this?

Comment: grant the user nopassword permission in /etc/sudoer file and restrict it to only the resources it requires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
--use-sudo-password
Indicates that a bootstrap operation is done using sudo, with the password specified by the -P (or --ssh-password) option.
```

a better way would be

```
-i IDENTITY_FILE, --identity-file IDENTITY_FILE
```

The SSH identity file used for authentication. Key-based authentication is recommended.

http://docs.opscode.com/knife_bootstrap.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an entry for the user in `/etc/sudoers` file to not prompt for password

You need to add an entry similar to the one below in `/etc/sudoers`

`<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

you can add this line to `/etc/sudoers` using chef `bash` resource or `execute` resource

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the current user to the sudoers group and give it password-less sudo access on that command:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux